# A property of unital commutative Banach *-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> Problem: Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a unital and commutative Banach $*$-algebra, and $\|x x^* \| = \|x\|^2, \forall x \in \mathcal{B}$. Prove that $\|x^2 \| = \|x \|^2, \forall x \in \mathcal{B}$.

Attempt: This seems like a simple algebra problem I can't seem to get the result. I can easily show $\|x^2 \| \le \|x \|^2$, but the other direction is giving me trouble. Can anyone give me some hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show that if $x=x^*$, then $\|x^2\|=\|x\|^2$ (quite easy).  Note that if $(xx^*)^*=xx^*$ for all $x\in\mathcal B$.  Then show that for any $x\in\mathcal B$, $\|x\|=\|x^*\|$  (also quite easy).  Then combine these results.

Comment: It also may be helpful to note that $\|x\|^4=(\|x\|^2)^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already observed these results but was silly in thinking I'm still missing something!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

$\|x^{\ast}\|^{2}=\|x^{\ast}(x^{\ast})^{\ast}\|=\|x^{\ast}x\|=\|xx^{\ast}\|=\|x\|^{2}$, so $\|x^{\ast}\|=\|x\|$.

Now 
\begin{align*}
\|x\|^{4}&=\|xx^{\ast}\|^{2}\\
&=\|(xx^{\ast})(xx^{\ast})^{\ast}\|\\
&=\|x^{2}(x^{\ast})^{2}\|\\
&\leq\|x^{2}\|\|(x^{\ast})^{2}\|\\
&=\|x^{2}\|\|(x^{2})^{\ast}\|\\
&=\|x^{2}\|\|x^{2}\|\\
&=\|x^{2}\|^{2}.
\end{align*}